# Python: numpy array to vtk stl-file creator. How to set spacing?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vtk

Dear Python and VTK users. I'm struggling with a generation of proper STL from huge 3D numpy array. The STL file is generated using VTK library, however when I open it in CAD software I can observe improper shape (due to lack of spacing). It seems that all those 'voxels' are of size (1,1,1), however, they should be of size (0.48, 0.48, 0.625) - data concernig pixel spacing is missing. I'm a newbie programmer and barely do I know python and VTK, so I need your help. How to add information about pixel spacing when I transform numpy arrays into VTK? **Answer found already.**

```
#my_numpy_array is defined in other part of my script

stack=my_numpy_array[:,:,:]
dataImporter = vtk.vtkImageImport()
data_string = stack.tostring()

dataImporter.CopyImportVoidPointer(data_string, len(data_string))
dataImporter.SetDataScalarTypeToUnsignedChar()
dataImporter.SetNumberOfScalarComponents(1)


w, d, h = stack.shape
dataImporter.SetDataExtent(0, h-1,0, d-1, 0, w-1)
dataImporter.SetWholeExtent(0, h-1,0, d-1, 0, w-1)

#here is the line that I was missing:
dataImporter.SetDataSpacing( 0.625, 0.48, 0.48)



threshold = vtk.vtkImageThreshold ()
threshold.SetInputConnection(dataImporter.GetOutputPort())
threshold.ThresholdByLower(128)
threshold.ReplaceInOn()
threshold.SetInValue(0)
threshold.ReplaceOutOn()
threshold.SetOutValue(1)
threshold.Update()

"""imageData = vtk.vtkImageData()
imageData.SetSpacing(0.48,0.48,0.625)
imageData.SetInputConnection(threshold.GetOutputPort())
imageData.Update())"""

dmc = vtk.vtkDiscreteMarchingCubes()
dmc.SetInputConnection(threshold.GetOutputPort())
dmc.GenerateValues(1, 1, 1)
dmc.Update()

writer = vtk.vtkSTLWriter()
writer.SetInputConnection(dmc.GetOutputPort())
writer.SetFileTypeToBinary()
writer.SetFileName("file.stl")
writer.Write()
```

I tried with vtkImageData(), however, it didn't work. I'd be extremely glad if you could help me solve this huge struggle.

Comment: Sorry for a forum spam, but I've figured it out. I just had to add this line:
dataImporter.SetDataSpacing( 0.625, 0.48, 0.48)

Comment: Good one @Zibi but I think you should formulate an answer. It's ok to answer your own question but please provide a good quality answer (perhaps by expanding a bit your commentary, showing the correct code in the relevant part).

Comment: Pardon. I wanted to paste a part of the code as the answer, but I couldn't (it's my first time on stackoverflow, so excuse me). Nonetheless, I was trying to add SetDataSpacing() in a wrong place, that's why it didn't work earlier. I have edited the OP with the correct part of the code